# Is it possible to assign a hotkey to switch between Activity and XML layout in Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio

Android Studio shows this button in the top left when an activity is open, which jumps to the corresponding activity layout when clicked:

[image]

Is it possible to assign a hotkey to this button? I've looked through the keymap page in the Preferences, but can't find anything for this button.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can add or confirm keyboard shortcuts at Keymap

`Navigate > Related Symbol`

Comment: ALT + CTRL + HOME is default shortcut.

Answer (score 1):

We can go related XML file from a class by pressing keyboard shortcut

```
Clr + Alt + Home
```

Answer (score 0):

just put the buildscript in the top above the plugins like that

```
buildscript {
repositories {
    google()
}



dependencies {

    classpath("androidx.navigation:navigation-safe-args-gradle-plugin:2.5.3")
}
```

}

```
plugins {
id 'com.android.application' version '7.3.0' apply false
id 'com.android.library' version '7.3.0' apply false
id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android' version '1.7.10' apply false
```

}